# Adding another search field in a custom search box

Tags: search

I'd like to add another criterium to search my posts, the custom field meta key is "function_camere", and I want to add another dropdown selector to choose a value for this new search criterium, any idea?

```
function wpb_demo_shortcode() {

global $wp_query;

$categories = wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_count'=> 1,
    'hierarchical'=> 1,
    'show_option_all'=>esc_html__('All destinations','sacconicase'),
    'echo'=> false,
));
$select = $wp_query->get('tipologia');
$select = ''== $select ? 0 : $select; // use 0 value if no query var is assigned
$taxonomy = wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'hierarchical'=> false,
    'name'=>'tipologia',

    'taxonomy' =>'tipologia',

    'selected' => $select,
    'show_option_all'=>esc_html__('Typology','sacconicase'),

    'value_field'=>'slug',
    'echo'=> false
));
$output = '<form class="sacconi_form" method:"get" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">'.
    $categories . $taxonomy .'<br></br>'.'<input type="submit" name="search" value="'. esc_html__( 'Search','sacconicase' ) .'" >'.
'</form>';

return $output;
  }

add_shortcode('ricerca', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a dropdown selector for the custom field meta key "function_camere" in your WordPress search form, you can modify the wpb_demo_shortcode function to include this new dropdown. This dropdown will allow users to select a value for the "function_camere" field, which will then be used as a search criterion.

Here's how you can modify the wpb_demo_shortcode function to include this functionality:

First, you need to retrieve the unique values for the "function_camere" custom field from the database. This will populate the dropdown options.
Add a new dropdown to the form for the "function_camere" field.
Modify the form submission to include this new criterion in the search query.
Below is the updated code for the wpb_demo_shortcode function:

```
function wpb_demo_shortcode() {
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;

    // Retrieve categories dropdown
    $categories = wp_dropdown_categories([
        'show_count' => 1,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_all' => esc_html__('All destinations', 'sacconicase'),
        'echo' => false,
    ]);

    // Retrieve tipologia dropdown
    $select = $wp_query->get('tipologia');
    $select = '' == $select ? 0 : $select;
    $taxonomy = wp_dropdown_categories([
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'name' => 'tipologia',
        'taxonomy' => 'tipologia',
        'selected' => $select,
        'show_option_all' => esc_html__('Typology', 'sacconicase'),
        'value_field' => 'slug',
        'echo' => false
    ]);

    // Retrieve unique values for 'function_camere' custom field
    $functionCamereValues = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'function_camere' ORDER BY meta_value");
    $functionCamereDropdown = '<select name="function_camere">';
    $functionCamereDropdown .= '<option value="">' . esc_html__('Select Function Camere', 'sacconicase') . '</option>';
    foreach ($functionCamereValues as $value) {
        $functionCamereDropdown .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($value) . '">' . esc_html($value) . '</option>';
    }
    $functionCamereDropdown .= '</select>';

    // Form output
    $output = '<form class="sacconi_form" method="get" action="' . home_url('/') . '">' .
              $categories . $taxonomy . $functionCamereDropdown . '<br><br>' .
              '<input type="submit" name="search" value="' . esc_html__('Search', 'sacconicase') . '">' .
              '</form>';

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('ricerca', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

This code creates a dropdown for the "function_camere" custom field, populated with its unique values. Users can select an option from this dropdown along with other criteria to refine their search. The form method is corrected to method="get" for proper submission. Ensure that the search results page handles this new query parameter appropriately.

Comment: I can see the new selector but it's not filtering :(